# How to remove blank columns and reorder the columns in desired order in powershell

Tags: powershell

I got a excel sheet ,which got values from server . I want to remove columns which have no value..I did that but resulted excel sheet column names are in alphabetical order.But I want them in desired order. If use Select-object to get desired order , it will give the removed columns again.Below is the code i used to remove blank columns.

```
$x = Import-Csv YourFile.csv
$f = $x[0] | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select name
$f | Add-Member -Name count -Type NoteProperty -Value 0
$f | %{
  $n = $_.Name
  $_.Count = @($x | Select $n -ExpandProperty $n | ? {$_ -ne ''}).count
}
$f = @($f | ? {$_.count -gt 0} | Select Name -expandproperty Name)

$x | Select $f | Export-Csv NewFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Get-Member reorders in alphabetical order. This means, that your issue is implemented in the very first operation. As far as I know, there is no way to stop Get-Member from messing with your order.

Comment: You might be able to do some string gymnastics on the first object to get the properties in the correct order with something like this (($x[0] | convertto-json -Compress) -replace('\{|\}')).split(',') -replace '^"|":(.)+$'

Comment: @AxelAndersen Following commands are not working if I  use ur command in first operation ...Could you please give   next commands in to order remove empty columns

Comment: You need to construct the initial $f objects to match the ones you get from your first operation, that can be achieved like this: $f = (($x[0] | convertto-json -Compress) -replace('\{|\}')).split(',') -replace '^"|":(.)+$' | Select-Object @{n='Name';e={$_}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Axel Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567337/axel-andersen) points out, `Get-Member` invariably returns an object's members *alphabetically sorted*.

Try the following approach, which uses `.psobject.Properties.Name` to get the column (property) names in the original order:

```
$rows = Import-Csv YourFile.csv
$columnNames = $rows[0].psobject.Properties.Name

$nonEmptyColumnNames = $columnNames.Where({ (@($rows.$_) -ne '').Count -gt 0 })

$rows | Select-Object $nonEmptyColumnNames | Export-Csv NewFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```